# 本の通り書いたプログラムで SyntaxError が発生してしまう

Tags: python, pygame, python-idle

何度も読み返して確認したのですが、全部同じプログラムなのにどうしてもエラーになります。

```
import pygame as pg, sys
pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))

while True:
    screen.fill(pg.Color("WHITE"))
    pg.draw.rect(screen, pg.Color("RED"), (100, 100, 100, 150))
　　pg.display.update()
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

pg.display.update()のpgの部分が赤くなってSyntaxErrorと出ます.
使用しているのはPython3.6のIDLEです。

Comment: 対象としている本を引用を含めて教えて下さい

Comment: [ゲーム作りで楽しく学ぶ Pythonのきほん | マイナビブックス](https://book.mynavi.jp/ec/products/detail/id=122784)
　　
[ゲーム作りで楽しく学ぶ Pythonのきほん: Google ブックス](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=g8w1EAAAQBAJ&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113)

Answer (score 3):

エラーメッセージは略さず表示されたままを全て質問に記述しましょう。
あるいはエディタ画面では質問のように表示されているのかもしれませんが、試しに実行させてみれば、このように表示されませんか？(ただしパス名は私が試した環境でのファイル名です)

```
  File "C:\Develop\Python\pg.py", line 8
    　　pg.display.update()
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid non-printable character U+3000
```

質問記事に転記した際に混入した訳ではなく、ソースコードをそのままコピペしたままなのであれば、該当行のインデントが半角空白4桁ではなく全角空白2桁になっています。
半角空白4桁に修正すれば動作するでしょう。

---

ちなみにPython-IDLEのエディタ画面にも「Run」メニューに「Check Module」というのがあって実行すればチェック出来ますが、Python 3.8 だと質問のように`pg`の部分が赤(というかピンク?)になって、「Syntax Error」のタイトルに「invalid character in idetifier」の文章でメッセージボックスが表示されます。

これが Python 3.9 または 3.10 だと、行の頭の全角空白がピンクになって、上記のように文章部分が「invalid non-printable character U+3000」に変わります。

おそらく参考にした書籍で使っているPythonの版数が3.6であるため、使うPythonの版数を合わせたのだと思われますが、マイナーバージョン(3.の直後の版数)が違えば両方ともインストール出来るはずですので、最新版(3.10)も入れておいて両方で確かめることも考えた方が良いでしょう。

---

さらに追記：
上記IDLEのチェックでふと思い直して Python 3.8 で実行してみたら、IDLEでの表示と同様にエラーメッセージが変わって以下のようになっていました。こちらが質問の状況の実態でしょう。
Python版数によってチェック内容が変わっているということですね。新しい版数の方がより問題の原因に近いメッセージになっています。

```
  File "C:\Develop\Python\pg.py", line 8
    　　pg.display.update()
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Answer (score 2):

エディタにはVisual Studio Codeをお勧めします。
全角空白の使用とか文法ミスを見つけてくれますので便利ですよ。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]